# kafka-console-consumer. ERROR Connection to node 0 could not be established.Broker may not be available

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to consume message from kafka in my local (windows 7 virtual desk top)

1. zookeeper and kafka are running on same local computer
2. Create topic

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --topic first_topic --create -- partitions 3 --replication-factor 1
Created successful
```

1. Produce message
   kafka-console-producer --broker-list 127.0.0.1:9092 --topic first_topic
   no error ,i just do Ctrl+C do end producing
2. Consume message

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --topic first_topic --from-beginning
ERROR : 
WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-71129] Connection to node 0 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

please help!

in server.properties setup

```
broker.id=0
advertised.port=9092
advertised.host.name=127.0.0.1
listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
```

Comment: Are you getting some error message from broker after starting it or after starting console-consumer?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are running in local computer, you don't require to add these below properties.

Comment out these.

```
advertised.port=9092
advertised.host.name=127.0.0.1
listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
```

2. Add/modify below properties in server.properties as below:

   ```
   zookeeper.connect=<computer name>:2181
   ```

   In zookeeper.properties :

   Create a folder say in D:/ drive and put that in zookeeper.properties as below

   dataDir=D:\\foldername\\zookeeper
3. You can use localhost instead 127.0.0.1 also in all the command.

Try these, it may help

Comment: thank you for your answer,  tried but still have same error message

Comment: Can you try these command and find out what ip / host name it is returning :
 zookeeper-shell.bat localhost:2181 then  run command in the shell once it opened -> get /brokers/ids/0 .

Comment: I run it  zookeeper-shell.bat localhost:2181 (after zookeeper was up  run this command) . I got Connecting to localhost:2181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is disabled

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null

Comment: Node does not exist : /brokers/ids/0

Comment: I think your broker is not running. You first run the zookeeper and don’t terminate the process, similarly in another window run the Kafka broker and don’t close the window. Now you open a another window and run these two commands one by one.

Comment: get /brokers/ids/0
{"listener_security_protocol_map":{"PLAINTEXT":"PLAINTEXT"},"endpoints":["PLAINT
EXT://H21JAFI00PS0167.nam.nsroot.net:9092"],"jmx_port":-1,"host":"H21JAFI00PS016
7.nam.nsroot.net","timestamp":"1554998247992","port":9092,"version":4}
cZxid = 0x18
ctime = Thu Apr 11 11:57:28 EDT 2019
mZxid = 0x18
mtime = Thu Apr 11 11:57:28 EDT 2019
pZxid = 0x18
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 1
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x1000005bad30000
dataLength = 230
numChildren = 0

Comment: Ok. Then use the hostname instead 127.0.0.1 in consumer command to connect. I think it will solve your issue.

Comment: I mean use below as the command for consumer :                                       
 kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server H21JAFI00PS016 7.nam.nsroot.net:9092 --topic first_topic --from-beginning

Comment: Thank you for your help!